# Unhandled exception at 0x00B84CD6 in DirectXGame.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000DC

Tags: c++

C++ DirectX11 visual studio 2012. I have declared my GKController1 class as a ref class.
I am new to C++ programming and I didn't write most of this code so I don't really understand why it's breaking. If you need anymore code just ask. Thanks.

Here's the code where it breaks:

Background.cpp file

```
int GameBackGround::PlayingGame()
{
    if (this->controller1->IsPauseRequested()) //Breaks here, it doesn't even allow me to step into the method, it just breaks
    {
        //Game Paused
        return 3;
    }
}`
```

Background.h file

```
GKController1^ controller1; 

//GKController1 file
bool GKController1::IsPauseRequested()
{
    if (gamepadConnected)
    {
        if (this->gamepadState.Gamepad.wButtons & XINPUT_GAMEPAD_BACK
            && !(this->previousGamepadState.Gamepad.wButtons & XINPUT_GAMEPAD_BACK))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return this->escKeyPressed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing more code I'd say you're probably trying to access memory offset from a null pointer value. Probably best that you get familiar with the basics of the language before you start trying to fix someone elses code. In short if `controller1` is a pointer and the containing object allows a state where that member variable can be a null pointer value you need to check it before accessing the memory it points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (this->controller1->IsPauseRequested()) //Breaks here, it doesn't even allow me to step into the method, it just breaks
```

`controller1` is almost certainly a bad pointer.  When you dereference it (`->IsPaurRequested()`) you receive an access violation because you are reading memory you don't own.

Where are you initializing it?  I see the declaration, but you need to initialize it somewhere.  The member is of the same type as the declaring class.  Why is it needed?  It looks like you're just passing everything through, why not just use `IsPauseRequested()` (`this->IsPauseRequested()`)?

Comment: Oh the horror of potentially endless instantiations ;)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Haha, oops, that's what I get for blindly copying the member type and not paying attention. Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to initialize it :). Thanks.